# Trouble jquery ui hover to fetch data from database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Having trouble to show the result of tooltip coming from database. here is the process of my code I got multiple months calendar using jquery ui and when user hover on the date it will show a tooltip having a list of event came from database and load it to div but I'm having trouble to fetch the data from database comparing the date that user hover.

Below are my code js and php

```
       $(document).ready(function () {
             $("event_calendar").datepicker(
            numberOfMonths: 3,
            showButtonPanel: true,
             );     

      $('td a').live('mouseenter', function () { 
            var day = $(this).text();
            var month = $(this).parent('.ui-datepicker').find('.ui-datepicker-month').text();
            var year  = $(this).parent('.ui-datepicker').find('.ui-datepicker-year').text();

            var dateSelected = month + day + year;

             $('.demo').html(date);
             $('#tooltip').load("event_list.php", {thisDate: dateSelected});
             $('#tootltip').css('visibility', 'visible')
       });


    });

event_list.php

$thisDate = $_REQUEST['thisDate'];

$qry = "SELECT * FROM event where eventdate = '$thisDate'";
        $result = mysql_query($qry) or die ("Error in query: $qry. " . mysql_error());
        while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)){
        echo $row->event_name;
        }

It doesnt show any output on <div id="tooltip"></div>
```

my date format is UNIX timestamps stored on mysql database

Comment: What is the output of event_list.php ? please write it also and suggest you filter data (`$thisDate`) before using it in Database query

Comment: @mamoo idont have any error and doesnt get any result show :(

Comment: I'd get the query and try it against your db with a sql tool, looks like the date format you pass is not correct...

Comment: @mamoo thank you for the reply I used UNIX timestamps for my date format stored in my mysql database

Comment: @battousay try using a developer console (firefrox, ie9, chrome got one), to see if it requests the page, and what result you get back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Don't use `$_REQUEST` superglobal, it's better (safer) to use `$_POST` (or `$_GET` depends on ajax call method)
2. Check what returns this javascript statement: `var dateSelected = month + day + year;` 
   I don't think it returns timestamp (you should make new `Date` object using this values and get timestamp using `getTime()` method, for example: 
   `var dateSelected = Date(year, month - 1, day).getTime() / 1000;`
   Check this for more information: [JavaScript Date Object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)
3. Validate content of `$thisDate` variable to prevent sql injection
4. Add `exit;` in the end of PHP script to ensure, that script exits after echoing all informations

Yours PHP script does not generate an MySQL error because query is not incorrect but it returns empty result. Print query in PHP script and you will see whats wrong in it using javascript console (as mentioned in comments to your question)

Comment: now I see month and year dosnt have the right value and Can'y get the right value on mouse over I searched this one [Jquery UI Get date on mouseover][1]

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847646/jquery-datepicker-get-the-date-on-mouseover-from-the-cell but the problem is I do have 3 clendar that's why it get the 3 value March , April and May, any jquery function to get the hover cell month and year value?

Comment: What are exactly values of this variables (year, month and day)?

Comment: Ok, I see the problem. The problem is, that `$(this).closest('.ui-datepicker')` gets all calendar with all of months, not the closest month table. So check this out: [http://jsfiddle.net/99cNA/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/99cNA/2/). In my edit I get closest datepicker group (`.ui-datepicker-group`) and get month and year from it.
Now you can get timestamp using `Date` object as I wrote in section 2 of my answer (but you must parse month name into number first)